# C++ : problem when trying to create an instance

Tags: c++

Still trying to get back into C++ and fumbling on differences from Java.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

#### Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test {
    public:
        int x, y;
        Test();
        virtual ~Test();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

#### Test.cpp

```
#include "Test.h"

Test::Test() {
    x = 0;
    y = 28;
}

Test::~Test()
{
    //dtor
}
```

#### My main app header (I'm using openFrameworks)

```
#ifndef _TEST_APP
#define _TEST_APP

#include "ofMain.h"
#include "Test.h"

class testApp : public ofBaseApp{

 public:
  void setup();
            [snip]
  Test test_obj;

};

#endif
```

#### test_app.cpp

```
#include "testApp.h"
#include "Test.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void testApp::setup(){
    test_obj = new Test();
}

[snip]
```

This should be straightforward, right? Define a class Test, declare a variable of class Test (test_obj) in test_app.h and then create an instance and assign it to that variable in the test_app.cpp file.

However I'm getting this error message from the compiler in the assignment line :

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((testApp*)this)->testApp::test_obj = (operator new(12u), (<statement>, ((Test*)<anonymous>)))’
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I not understanding here?

Comment: beware of your header guards, identifiers beginning by an underscore and followed by a upper case character are reserved and should not be used in application code.

Comment: is that so? interesting. Those flags were automatically created by CodeBlocks so I guess a lot of people must be using them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use `new` with pointers in C++. It is different from Java.

Your declaration of `Test test_obj` should be `Test* test_obj;`

However, you can declare variable simply on stack like `Test test_obj;`. Doing this means that you don't have to `new` the object, the constructor is automatically called and hence, object is initialized.

**To expand on it a little bit more:**

There are two ways of object creation in C++.

1. Test test_obj;
2. Test* test_obj = new Test();

First one creates an object on the stack and it is automatically destroyed (destructor is called) when object goes out of scope.

For the second one, the object is created on heap and you have to explicitly call `delete` on the object to destroy it like this:

```
delete test_obj;
```

Remember, there is no automatic memory management in C++, therefore, you have to remember to `delete` everything that you create with `new`.

Comment: +1. And doing so, the object will also be automatically freed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Splitting hairs, perhaps, but there _is_ automatic memory management in C++: as you say, the destructor is automatically called for objects when they go out of scope. Fairer to say there is no automatic garbage collection for heap objects, which is why one should use `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` for them (and in doing so, you don't have to `delete` everything that you create with `new`).

Comment: @beldaz: Good points but for somebody who is at a very basic level, I thought to keep it simple :)

Comment: @interstar: Since you are coming from Java and are now used to having GC, read up on [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) and then check out [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/).

Answer (score 1):

```
Test *p = new Test();
```

Get into the habit of using [auto_ptr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr) or [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) or [unique_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html) rather than using raw pointers in C++.

Comment: Hmm, I'd rather say "get into the habit of not using *any* kind of pointers" first. Once a Java programmer has adjusted to the idea that it is often better to just put the variable on the stack, you can introduce smart pointers to cover the cases where pointer semantics are needed.

Answer (score 0):

`new Test()` returns a `Test *`, i.e. a pointer.  You cannot assign this to a `Test` object.  You could do `test_obj = Test();`, though.

Comment: Why would you assign Test() to test_obj?  Just because the syntax passes the type checker?  *Coding by guess-work will fail.*

Comment: @Roger: I'm not saying you *should* do that; merely that you can.

Comment: Congratulations on that 10K score!!. Good going

Answer (score 0):

In your test_app.h, you are declaring a Test object, not a pointer to a test object. Therefore in the constructor you do not need to create a new instance of Test on the heap. The error you are getting means that you are trying to assign a Test* to a variable of Test type.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error, this line :

```
Test test_obj;
```

should have been :

```
Test *test_obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be either:

```
Test *test_obj;
//...
test_obj = new Test;
// ...
delete test_obj;
```

Or:

```
Test test_obj;
```

Then there's no need to release `test_obj` since it's automatically done as soon as it gets out of scope.